# using arrays in gulp.series() or gulp.parallel()

Tags: node.js, gulp

i have dynamically created gulp tasks, which works fine. but executing the tasks by passing an array to `gulp.series()` or `gulp.parallel()` doesn't work.

imho this should work according to the documentation: 
https://gulp.readme.io/docs/gulpseriestasks 
https://gulp.readme.io/docs/gulpparalleltasks

this is a simplified version of what i am trying to do:

```
var tasks = ['clean', 'build', 'images'];
gulp.task('main', gulp.series('init', tasks));
```

`'init'` gets executed without problems, but it seems that `tasks`just gets ignored.

any idea how I can use the taks array inside `gulp.series()` or `gulp.parallel()`?

**update:** *I am using gulp 4.0.0-alpha.2*

**final update:** as I just found out the problem was, that my array has been asynchronically generated. it was empty when I tried my task, so I got no error messages. my code works fine.

thanks for any help!

Answer (score 4):

It looks like those methods expect multiple tasks to be passed as arguments, so you could call `apply` on them and pass an array:

```
gulp.task('main', gulp.series.apply(gulp, ['clean', 'build', 'images']))
```

(Disclaimer: I haven't tested this myself)

*edit*

Okay, I see what you're doing. You need to pass *either* a string, a function, or an Array. You can't mix and match.

So what you probably want to do is:

```
var tasks = ['clean', 'build', 'images'];
gulp.task('main', gulp.series(['init'].concat(tasks)));
```

Or, using the array spread operator:

```
var tasks = ['clean', 'build', 'images'];
gulp.task('main', gulp.series(['init', ...tasks]));
```

Comment: thanks for your answer - but as I just found out, my code works fine. the content of the array was asynchronically generated and empty at "compile time". seems like gulp is "precompiling" the tasks - because when I debugged my array with a anonymous function, the content was there - but actually it got never "injected" into the task.